# How can I handle a SQL query by using convert decimal string to datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to convert a decimal string to datetime:

```
20160709.0000000 => 09-07-2016 (dd-MM-YYYY)
```

but the code here returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
select 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(nvarchar(50), MyBirthDate), 112) BirthDate, Test, Test2
from 
    tbl
```

This code also does not work:

```
select 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '20160709.0000000'), 112)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to convert `string` to `int` or else you can use `replace` function

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE('20160709.0000000', '.0000000', ''))
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(20160709.0000000 AS INT )), 112)
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(20160709.0000000 AS INT )))
```

Comment: The first is needlessly complicated. We know, that there is a date in format yyyymmdd. Just use `LEFT(theValue,8)`. This `REPLACE` might even break, if the numbers of zeros is not the same in all cases.. And the second wil break, if OP really means a string type with *convert decimal string*

Comment: Sorry, which remaining answers? Your second and third are similar. I'd prefer the one with `,112`, just to avoid culture related confusions. but `CAST(20160709.0000000 AS INT )` will have a problem if you pass in the argument as string...

Answer (score 3):

The unseparated format you show (`yyyymmdd`) will be casted implicitly. I hope I do understand your *convert decimal string* correctly. Assuming, the value is of string type, you can cast this directly, just cut off the part you need:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='20160709.0000000';
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@s,8) AS DATETIME);
```

The result

```
2016-07-09 00:00:00.000
```

### Hint

This solution would just work the same with the argument as decimal value, due to the implicit cast to string while passing into `LEFT`:

```
DECLARE @s DECIMAL(20,10)=20160709.0000000;
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@s,8) AS DATETIME);
```

Comment: Try changing the '.0000000' first though, it will not affect the time, it will stay 00:00:000

Comment: @MVCNoob Sure, but look at the name of the column: *MyBirthDate*. Do you think, time matters :-) And btw: If the OP would have needed the time, the example - for sure - would be with a time fraction...

Comment: Just trying to help with both situations since you asked for both solutions. Glad that you found your answer :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST(20160709.0000000 AS INT )), 112)
```

Comment: OP wrote *convert decimal string*... I don't know, if I read it correctly, but your answer would break, if the value is of a string type...